# How to set value with NX option and expire using ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I'm using ServiceStack.Redis to execute commands on REDIS.

I would like to simply set value with expire and NX option (which is : set only if not exists).

**SET resource_name my_value NX PX 30000**

The problem is that ServiceStack.Redis client has only two methods:

```
client.SetValue() // <-- this one has Timespan expire argument
client.SetValueIfNotExists() // <-- this one doesn't
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

I see a `public bool SetValueIfNotExists(string key, string value, TimeSpan expireIn)` in `RedisClient.cs`, [line 183](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L183)

Please mention what version are you using if you don't see it in your included package.

Comment: I have version: 5.1.0

Comment: It is there in 5.1.0 https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/v5.1.0/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L189

Comment: oww. just noticed - It is in RedisClient, but not in IRedisClient ... a mistake ?

Comment: And only in RedisClient, unless it is seen as an extension, yes it would be an omission on the interface.

Comment: @lukasz FYI these APIs have now been added to IRedisClient and available from the [latest v5.8.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).